Fetch portion of Admin URL
I would like to fetch some portions of URL of Admin Page.Like I would like to fetch admin.php?page=my-custom-page from this URL https://example.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=my-custom-page.
How can I do that ?

Detecting Wordpress admin screens using URL parameters can be a pain in the butt and also raise security issues. However, there's a whole set of built in functions ready to help... but first off, why are you trying to detect an admin page using a funky string like admin.php?page=my-custom-page is this an admin page? an options page? a custom post type? each has it's own way of implementing in WP admin.

Thanks @Simon. Actually I am learning plugin development. I would like to load a CSS file for some specific Admin Pages.

@Foysal you can use this action to do that : https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/current_screen/
